# Expression Func in Selector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I created two selector using Exp-Func I want to execute both in a single query. Code is as follows:

```
Expression<Func<Scholar, ScholarCultureWatchListView>> selector = z => new ScholarCultureWatchListView
{
    ScholarId = z.ID,
    Name = z.FirstName + " " + z.LastName                                               
};

Expression<Func<Scholar, ScholarCultureWatchListView>> selector2 = z => new ScholarCultureWatchListView
{
    Grade = z.CurrentGrade
};
var result= from s in db.Scholars
            select new ScholarCultureWatchListView
                {
            **?????What is write here (selector, selector2)**
                }



public class ScholarCultureWatchListView
{
    public long ScholarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
    public bool? HoldOverSkip { get; set; }
    public Grade? GradeHoldOver { get; set; }
    public bool? Iep { get; set; }
    public int Tardies { get; set; }
    public int Absences { get; set; }
    public int YtdSuspensions { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

please solve my problem.
Thanks

Comment: You are setting completely different properties in each case. Can you post the code for the ScholarCultureWatchListView - or at least a list of it's public properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get two separate instances of `ScholarCultureWatchListView` returned from a single call, you can do for example this (and you don't need selectors at all):

```
var result = from s in db.Scholars
             select new[]
             {
                 new ScholarCultureWatchListView
                 {
                     ScholarId = s.ID,
                     Name = s.FirstName + " " + z.LastName
                 },
                 new ScholarCultureWatchListView
                 {
                     Grade = z.CurrentGrade
                 },
             };
```

Comment: I want to return single instance. but I have to select Field dynamically. so I want to create many selector and execute them to get result in single instance on the basis of given conditions.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to achieve. Many "selectors" imply many results, so what exactly are you going to use so called selectors for?